# Grep exact string not working when piped

Tags: grep

If I `cat` text file containing `mysqld_safe` and `mysqld` then `grep -w` works as expected. But when piped with `PS` output it does not work.

```
ps -ef | grep  -w mysqld
```

Output's both lines.

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
/usr/libexec/mysqld
```

I am expecting only `mysqld`. I'm aware of exclude option `grep -v mysqld_safe`.

**Version  - `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1`**

Comment: Well, `grep '\bmysqld\b'` cannot find `mysqld` in `mysqld_safe`. Just because `_` is a word char, and there is no word boundary between `d` and `_`.

Comment: Assuming bash, you must single quote the regular expression. As it stands, the regex 2 seen by grep is 'bmysqlb' and should not match any of these lines. ["A non-quoted backslash (\\) is the escape character. It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: It's not a homework, I'm trying to resolve monitoring issue. I want to filter this first and then json output for a software. Also that \b is something I learned just few minutes ago before posting question here. There's a lot of similar question and I've gone through most of them that's how I came across grep boundary.

Comment: if you have pgrep, I think using `pgrep -x mysqld` would be better choice than `ps + grep`

Comment: pgrep does the job. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `pgrep`, using `pgrep -x mysqld` would be better choice than `ps + grep`

From `man pgrep`

```
   pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes

   -x, --exact
          Only match processes whose names (or command line if -f is specified) exactly match the pattern.

   -l, --list-name
          List the process name as well as the process ID.  (pgrep only.)

   -c, --count
          Suppress  normal  output;  instead print a count of matching processes.  When count does not match any‐
          thing, e.g. returns zero, the command will return non-zero value.

   -n, --newest
          Select only the newest (most recently started) of the matching processes.
```